# Python-Classifier-Xgboost - show cv with params, duration time, score in GridSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, cross-validation

I have a problem with showing information about cross validation in `xgboost`.
In scikit-learn: when I use GridSearchCV I have output warning like:

```
[CV 1/2] END mlp__activation=relu, mlp__alpha=0.01, mlp__hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), mlp__max_iter=300, mlp__random_state=20, mlp__solver=lbfgs;, score=0.812 total time=   5.3s[CV 2/2] 
END mlp__activation=relu, mlp__alpha=0.01, mlp__hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), mlp__max_iter=300, mlp__random_state=20, mlp__solver=lbfgs;, score=0.824 total time=   6.3s[CV 2/2] 
END mlp__activation=tanh, mlp__alpha=0.01, mlp__hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), mlp__max_iter=300, mlp__random_state=1, mlp__solver=lbfgs;, score=0.844 total time=   7.7s[CV 2/2] 
END mlp__activation=tanh, mlp__alpha=0.01, mlp__hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), mlp__max_iter=300, mlp__random_state=20, mlp__solver=lbfgs;, score=0.843 total time=   7.6s[CV 1/2] 
END mlp__activation=tanh, mlp__alpha=0.01, mlp__hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), mlp__max_iter=300, mlp__random_state=20, mlp__solver=lbfgs;, score=0.833 total time=   9.3s[CV 1/2] 
END mlp__activation=relu, mlp__alpha=0.01, mlp__hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), mlp__max_iter=300, mlp__random_state=1, mlp__solver=lbfgs;, score=0.832 total time=   9.7s[CV 1/2] 
END mlp__activation=tanh, mlp__alpha=0.01, mlp__hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), mlp__max_iter=300, mlp__random_state=1, mlp__solver=lbfgs;, score=0.833 total time=  13.0s[CV 2/2] 
END mlp__activation=relu, mlp__alpha=0.01, mlp__hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), mlp__max_iter=300, mlp__random_state=1, mlp__solver=lbfgs;, score=0.844 total time=  12.8s
```

So... I have params + score + time + CV (number part).

Now when I try in `xgboost` and `verbose=3` I do not have this.

Here's what I'm doing:

```py
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

params_str_dict = {'n_estimators': [10,30,50,100], 'max_depth': [50,100,300],  'learning_rate': [0.5, 1], 'objective': ['binary:logistic'], 'verbosity': [3]}

model = XGBClassifier()
step_name = "xgb"
step_param_name = 'xgb__' 

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
                        # (scale_name, scale),
                        (step_name, model)
                        ])

model_GS = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, 
                    param_grid=params_str_dict, 
                    n_jobs=n_jobs, 
                    cv=custom_cv,
                    scoring=scoring,
                    verbose=4)

old_stdout = sys.stdout
log_file = open("cv.log","w")
sys.stdout = log_file
with parallel_backend('multiprocessing'):
    model_GS.fit(X_train, y_train)
    model_scoring_gs_train = model_GS.score(X_train, y_train)
            
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
    log_file.close()
```

Can I do something with this?

How change my code / warning / verbose (only 1-3) to show time + score + cv + params?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that verbosity being set in two places. This line controls the verbosity of `XGBoost`, which is likely printing out information that is not relevant to the task:

```py
params_str_dict = {
  # ...
  'verbosity': [3]
}
```

If this setting is removed, and `verbose=3` is added in the `GridSearchCV` object, the result should show time + score + cv fold + the relevant parameters:

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 24 candidates, totalling 120 fits
[CV 2/5] END xgb__learning_rate=0.5, xgb__max_depth=50, xgb__n_estimators=10, xgb__objective=binary:logistic;, score=0.969 total time=   0.7s
[CV 1/5] END xgb__learning_rate=0.5, xgb__max_depth=50, xgb__n_estimators=10, xgb__objective=binary:logistic;, score=0.968 total time=   0.8s
[CV 3/5] END xgb__learning_rate=0.5, xgb__max_depth=50, xgb__n_estimators=10, xgb__objective=binary:logistic;, score=0.969 total time=   0.8s
[CV 4/5] END xgb__learning_rate=0.5, xgb__max_depth=50, xgb__n_estimators=10, xgb__objective=binary:logistic;, score=0.969 total time=   0.9s
[CV 5/5] END xgb__learning_rate=0.5, xgb__max_depth=50, xgb__n_estimators=10, xgb__objective=binary:logistic;, score=0.974 total time=   1.1s
[CV 3/5] END xgb__learning_rate=0.5, xgb__max_depth=50, xgb__n_estimators=30, xgb__objective=binary:logistic;, score=0.968 total time=   1.8s
```

---

**Minimal reproducible example**:

```py
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
X_train, y_train = make_classification(n_samples=10_000)

params_str_dict = {"xgb__n_estimators": [10, 30, 50, 100], "xgb__max_depth": [50, 100, 300], "xgb__learning_rate": [0.5, 1], "xgb__objective": ["binary:logistic"]}

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[("xgb", xgb.XGBClassifier())])
model_GS = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=pipe,
    param_grid=params_str_dict,
    n_jobs=-1,
    cv=5,
    verbose=3,
).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Ok its work.. but... When i want export to file -  i dont see. My script save "cv information" after fit. And every script its ok. But when i use your advice - 2 minutes after finish script on the output in Visual Studio Code i see information about CV. I dont understand why. `code`
    2023-01-02 09:55:26, loop_pred_kal_detail_start, model 154, XGBClassifier
    2023-01-02 09:55:26 finish_export_start_data
    [CV 2/2] END xgb__learning_rate=0.5, xgb__max_depth=50, xgb__n_estimators=10, xgb__objective=binary:logistic;, score=0.843 total time= 0.2s `code`

Comment: The script has been executed - written to a file
"Fitting 3 folds for each of 4 candidates, totaling 12 fits" (I reduced the number of cvs and n_samples).
CV displayed in output. Maybe this is a problem with fast script and output... or visual studio code? Do you have the same, i.e. CV is displayed with a delay?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but that sounds like a separate question about file-io and multiprocessing. If you have another question, you can ask a new one.

Comment: Yes, you have right. My script  containt save to file. information about cv is displayed 2 minutes after the end of the script in output and is not visible in the file.